# AppleScript - Script To Make Current URL Change To A JavaScript

Tags: applescript

This is my current code.

```
    tell application "Google Chrome" to set the URL of the front document to "Javascript:buy();"
```

It doesn't allow me to use the Javascript though, what do I need to do to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You execute javascript in Chrome with the "execute javascript" command.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    tell window 1 to tell active tab
        set URL to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896927/applescript-script-to-make-current-url-change-to-a-javascript"
        repeat until not loading
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        set myVar to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('user-details')[0].childNodes[1].text"
    end tell
end tell

return myVar
```

.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    tell window 1 to tell active tab
        set the URL to "Javascript:buy();"
    end tell
end tell
```